# Varnish first request has max-age=0

Tags: wordpress, varnish

I got Varnish to almost work with Wordpress and Total Cache.

But isvarnishworking.com is telling me that age is 0. The funny thing is that if I try again for the same URL, it all works fine and I can see age is no longer 0

It does that for every URL I try. I can verify this in the browser too.

What could explain that upon first request (and for all clients), the max-age is 0 but then from 2nd request it is fine  ?

I could understand that if the cache was emptied and it was only doing it on first request. But here it is for the first request per client.

vcl_recv:

```
# Drop any cookies sent to Wordpress.
 if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
unset req.http.cookie;
 }

# Anything else left?
if (!req.http.cookie) {
 unset req.http.cookie;
}
```

vcl_fetch:

```
 # Drop any cookies Wordpress tries to send back to the client.
   if (!(req.url ~ "wp-(login|admin)")) {
    unset beresp.http.set-cookie;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The Varnish header "Age" is not the same as the Cache Control parameter "max-age". This is just telling you that the object is just now entering the cache. 5s later you should see "Age: 5".

Specifically from [sec 14.6 of RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.6)

> The Age response-header field conveys the sender's estimate of the
>         amount of time since the response (or its revalidation) was
>         generated at the origin server. A cached response is "fresh" if
>         its age does not exceed its freshness lifetime.

Comment: yes, I understand that. So you confirm that upon first request it is normal that the value is 0. Then if I wait 10 seconds and request the resource again, age should be 10, regardless of who made the request ? Because it is not the case here. It is always 0 on first request of a given client, event if another client requested the resource before. That in my opinion is not the expected behaviour, hence the result on isvarnishworking.com

Comment: I see what you mean. Have you modified vcl_hash? It sounds as if the originating client IP, User-Agent or another request-specific value is being used as part of hash.

Comment: the only thing I've done in the default.vcl is adding a bit of code to vcl_fetch and vcl_recv. Please see edit in my post. I have not changed vcl_hash.

Comment: Very interesting... perhaps a "Vary: User-Agent" from the origin? None of what you've shown seems like it should lead to this...

Answer (score 0):

Great, Varnish's answer to this problem is that I should get a Varnish Plus subscription if I want help.

I guess I'll use something else then.

Comment: No "Vary" headers coming from origin?